# python ignoring one of the 2 conditions in maya

Tags: python, maya

I'm pretty new with python (20days) but I already created few stuff in maya, for example pickers, ik-fk snap, and few more things. Now I'm trying to create a button to mirror the pose.

the problem is that i must give 2 conditions to my if cycle but maya is ignoring the second condition

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.select('arm_lf_FK_ctrl1', 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl2', 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl3')
baseOBJ = cmds.ls(sl=True)
cmds.select('arm_rt_FK_ctrl1', 'arm_rt_FK_ctrl2', 'arm_rt_FK_ctrl3')
targetOBJ = cmds.ls(sl=True)
attr = ['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ', 'rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ', 'IK' ]



for i in range(len (attr) ):

    for x in range(len (targetOBJ) ):
        if (cmds.attributeQuery(attr[i], node = targetOBJ[x], exists = True) \
        and cmds.getAttr(targetOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i], lock = False)): 
            newValue = cmds.getAttr(baseOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i])
            cmds.setAttr(baseOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i], newValue)
        else:
            pass
```

the error is:
Error: `RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 17: setAttr: The attribute 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl1.translateX' is locked or connected and cannot be modified. #`

but in the if cycle I wrote: `cmds.getAttr(targetOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i], lock = False)`

any hint?

EDIT SOLUTION:

here is the code fixed

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.select('arm_lf_FK_ctrl1', 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl2', 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl3')
baseOBJ = cmds.ls(sl=True)
cmds.select('arm_rt_FK_ctrl1', 'arm_rt_FK_ctrl2', 'arm_rt_FK_ctrl3')
targetOBJ = cmds.ls(sl=True)
attr = ['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ', 'rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ', 'IK' ]



    for i in range(len (attr) ):

        for x in range(len (baseOBJ) ):
            if (cmds.attributeQuery(attr[i], node = baseOBJ[x], exists = True) \
            and cmds.getAttr(baseOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i], lock = False)): 
                newValue = cmds.getAttr(baseOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i])
                cmds.setAttr(targetOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i], newValue)
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: you write `lock=false` for targetOBJ object, then you want to set the attribute of baseOBJ, so it's different object

Comment: mmm it makes sense but I had already tried. The object in the 2 groups are the same, just the base is one side, and the target the other side. The attribute locked on one obj, are locked on both obj. By the way I will try as soon as possible some other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify

```
cmds.getAttr(item + attribute, lock=True)
```

even if you are checking for an attribute you expect to be locked: the 'lock = true' says 'tell me the lock state', *not* 'tell me if lock is true'.

You can do this a little more simply using three common python tricks (and also by not adding the extra selections, which will just duplicate the lists you've passed in)

The first is to use a foreach loop --  getting values directly out of the list -- instead of using array indices. This is the standard method for doing loops in python.  So instead of

```
for index in range(len(list_of_things)):
    do_something(list_of_things[index])
```

you just do

```
for item in list_of_things:
   do_something(item)
```

The second is to use `zip()` to match up to lists and loop over them as pairs:  This makes it much easier to write loops that read cleanly as you keep values in sync.

The final thing is to use `try...except` and allow some kinds of errors to happen rather than pre-checking. This is a common python trick since exceptions are not expensive and the resulting code is often much more readable.

Putting these together you could do the same code like this:

```
sources = ('arm_lf_FK_ctrl1', 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl2', 'arm_lf_FK_ctrl3')
targets  = ('arm_rt_FK_ctrl1', 'arm_rt_FK_ctrl2', 'arm_rt_FK_ctrl3')
attr = ('.translateX', '.translateY', '.translateZ', '.rotateX', '.rotateY', '.rotateZ', '.IK' )

for source, target in zip(sources, targets):
    for attrib in attr:
        try:
            val = cmds.getAttr(source + attrib)
            cmds.setAttr(target + attrib, val)
        except Exception as e:
            print 'skipped', source + attrib, target + attrib
```

In this case Maya will throw a `RuntimeError` if you pass it a bad object, a bad attribute, or if you try to set a locked attribute.  You'll really want to be more careful with the check than I was here, depending on what you wish to do when the system tries to do something impossible.

One last trick that will make your life easier is to separate out your condition checks from the logic. Instead of

```
 if (cmds.attributeQuery(attr[i], node = baseOBJ[x], exists = True) \
        and cmds.getAttr(baseOBJ[x] + '.' + attr[i], lock = False)):
```

You may find it easier in the long run to do :

```
  exists, locked = False
  try:
      exists = cmds.ls(object + attrib) is not None
      locked = cmds.getAttr(object + attrib, lock = True)
  except:
      pass # if the object or attrib is missing, both vals will still be false    
  if exists and not locked:
      #do something
```

writing it this way makes it easier to insert debug printouts when things go wrong.

Comment: sorry I'm trying your code but I can't make it work. I have a lot of errors, I fixed the indent, i added the t seAttr but I still have error. did you try to test it?  Thanks

Comment: I fixed the sample - missing attributes raise `ValueError` instead of `RuntimeError`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know maya, but it looks like the issue is happening in the first condition itself, thus the second is being ignored. moreover the exception says issue while running ***setAttr***. This function will be call when you run an ***attributeQuery***, saying ***exists = True***, which would essentially mean you will end up adding the attribute if not already present.

Comment: querying the existence was is because not necessarily all the attribute in the list attr exist in all of the obj in baseOBJ. This is just a test. When the script will be complete the list will be empty and will be up to the user select the obj and the script must know which attribute can set and which ones no.